# Context menu on TableRow<Object> does not show up on first right click

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, contextmenu

So I followed this example on using context menu with TableViews from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328115801/https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/). I noticed that using this code

```
row.contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()))
.then(rowMenu)
.otherwise((ContextMenu)null));
```

does not show up on first right click on a row with values. I need to right click on that row again for the context menu to show up. I also tried this code(which is my first approach, but not using it anymore because I've read somewhere that [that](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328115801/https://www.marshall.edu/genomicjava/2013/12/30/javafx-tableviews-with-contextmenus/) guide is the best/good practice for anything related about context menu and tableview), and it displays the context menu immediately

```
if (row.getItem() != null) {
    rowMenu.show(row, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
}
else {
    // do nothing
}
```

but my problem with this code is it throws a NullPointerException whenever i try to right click on a row that has no data.

What could I possibly do to prevent NullPointerException while having the context menu show up immediately after a right click? In my code, I also have a code that a certain menu item in the context menu will be disabled based on the property of the myObject binded to row, that's why i need the context menu to pop up right away.

I noticed this too with the first block of code. Even if the property of myObject has already changed, it still has a menu item enabled/disabled unless I right click on that row again. I hope that you could help me. Thank you!

Here is a MCVE:

```
public class MCVE_TableView extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    BorderPane myBorderPane = new BorderPane();
    TableView<People> myTable = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn<People, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<People, Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>();

    ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();

    ObservableList<People> peopleList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    peopleList.add(new People("John Doe", 23));

    nameColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("Name"));

    ageColumn.setMinWidth(100);
    ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(
        new PropertyValueFactory<>("Age"));

    myTable.setItems(peopleList);
    myTable.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, ageColumn);

    myTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
        TableRow<People> row = new TableRow<>();

        row.setOnContextMenuRequested((event) -> {
            People selectedRow = row.getItem();
            rowMenu.getItems().clear();

            MenuItem sampleMenuItem = new MenuItem("Sample Button");
            if (selectedRow != null) {
                if (selectedRow.getAge() > 100) {
                    sampleMenuItem.setDisable(true);
                }

                rowMenu.getItems().add(sampleMenuItem);
            }
            else {
                event.consume();
            }

            /*if (row.getItem() != null) { // this block comment displays the context menu instantly
                rowMenu.show(row, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            }
            else {
                // do nothing
            }*/

            // this requires the row to be right clicked 2 times before displaying the context menu
            row.contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(row.itemProperty()))
            .then(rowMenu)
            .otherwise((ContextMenu)null));
        });

        return row;
    });

    myBorderPane.setCenter(myTable);

    Scene scene = new Scene(myBorderPane, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setTitle("MCVE");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}
Here is the People Class

```
public class People {
SimpleStringProperty name;
SimpleIntegerProperty age;
public People(String name, int age) {
    this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
}

public SimpleStringProperty NameProperty() {
    return this.name;
}
public SimpleIntegerProperty AgeProperty() {
    return this.age;
}
public String getName() {
    return this.name.get();
}
public int getAge() {
    return this.age.get();
}
```

}

Edit: MCVE added

Edit2: Updated the MCVE. Still requires to be right-clicked twice before the contextMenu pops up

Comment: Hi! I just added a MCVE. Thank you

Comment: thanks :) the NPE comes from not checking if selectedItem is null (before accessing its getAge) .. no idea why it is not shown on first click into a not-empty row, might be a bug

Comment: maybe not a bug: you seem to be re-creating the contextMenu on every request - do it once at instantiation time and bind that single (per-row) contextMenu to its contextMenuProperty if not empty

Comment: After creating a contextMenu at instantation time, how could I use that and bind the single (per-row) contextMenu? `if (row.contextMenuProperty() != null) {
                        row.getContextMenu().addAll(edit, merge, unmergeSchedule, delete);
                    }`. I don't know how could I use the contextMenu that is created at instantiation time

Comment: What I tried to do is create the contextMenu at instantiation time, and clear the items inside that menu every time I select a row. I have a strong feeling that I am doing this wrong..

Comment: I have updated the MCVE. NPE now is not present as I've folowed one of your suggestions (check if selectedItem is null). contextMenu still seems to pop-up after right-clicking twice even if contextMenu is created at instantiation time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below's a code snippet as a quick demonstration of how-to/where-to instantiate and configure a per-row ContextMenu. It

- creates a ContextMenu/MenuItem for each TableRow at the row's instantiation time
- creates a conditional binding that binds the menu to the row's contextMenuProperty if not empty (just the same as you did)
- configures the contextMenu in an onShowing handler, depending on the current item (note: no need for a guard against null, because the conditional binding will implicitly guarantee to not show the the menu in that case)

The snippet:

```
myTable.setRowFactory(tv -> {
    TableRow<People> row = new TableRow<>() {
      ContextMenu rowMenu = new ContextMenu();
      MenuItem sampleMenuItem = new MenuItem("Sample Button");
      {
          rowMenu.getItems().addAll(sampleMenuItem);
          contextMenuProperty()
              .bind(Bindings
                  .when(Bindings.isNotNull(itemProperty()))
                  .then(rowMenu).otherwise((ContextMenu) null));
          rowMenu.setOnShowing(e -> {
              People selectedRow = getItem();
              sampleMenuItem.setDisable(selectedRow.getAge() > 100);
          });
      }

    };
    return row;
});
```